# Admob Javascript Need reward video listeners after completed video

Tags: javascript, admob, phaser-framework, rewardedvideoad, cordova-admob

Hi guys I need some help implementing reward video listeners. 
I have a basic setup of admob nothing else other than using the plugin https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro.git

SO Simply better said I need to reward my players after watching the video how do I do it??

```
//this is my admob.js///////////////////////////////////////////////////////
var admobid = {};
if( /(android)/i.test(navigator.userAgent) ) { 
    admobid = { // for Android
        banner: '',
        interstitial: '',
        rewardvideo: 'my code etc',

    };
} else if(/(ipod|iphone|ipad)/i.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
    admobid = { // for iOS
        banner: '',
        interstitial: '',
        rewardvideo: 'my code etc',
    };
} else {
    admobid = { // for Windows Phone
        banner: '',
        interstitial: '',
    };
}
        if (AdMob) AdMob.createBanner( {
        adId: admobid.banner, 
        isTesting: false,
        overlap: true,
        offsetTopBar: false, 
        position: AdMob.AD_POSITION.BOTTOM_CENTER,
        bgColor: 'black'
   });



if (AdMob) AdMob.prepareInterstitial( {adId:admobid.interstitial, autoShow:false} );
if (AdMob) AdMob.prepareRewardVideoAd({ adId:admobid.rewardvideo, autoShow:false} );
```

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////bellow is a simple function used in my game

```
///now with this I do my reward video call in a function in my game
///this bellow gets called when a button is hit and launches the reward 
///video


 freecoinsss:function()
    {   
     if (AdMob) AdMob.showRewardVideoAd();
    },
```

now my problem is how can I get the eventlistener with a function awarding my players for watching the video 
"this is the function I want to call to award players" rewardforvideo();
coding in phaser btw

```
rewardforvideo:function()
{
 var reward = 50;
 var cash = localstorage.getItem('money');
 var newcash = (reward+cash);
 localstorage.setItem('money',newcash)

},
```

I found this https://developers.google.com/admob/android/rewarded-video-adapters
but Im stuck implementing it HElppppppp :(!!!!

Answer (score 0):

ok, after much investigation, I have this working as [from here](https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-admob-pro/blob/master/docs/README.md):

```
if(AdMob) {
    AdMob.showRewardVideoAd();
    document.addEventListener('onAdPresent', function(data){ 
        if(data.adType == 'rewardvideo') { 
            alert( data.rewardType ); // coins if you're using the test ID
            alert( data.rewardAmount ); // 10 if you're using the test ID
        } 
    });
}
```

I'm using the cordova-admob-pro plugin and using CLI to build for Android (at least for the moment)
I hope this helps someone.

Comment: Ok so that right there is listening the commands or you’re still having trouble with that and this is what you have and your stuck here?

Comment: This is where I was stuck, couldn't get the listener to return the reward type and its amount. Now, this is the implementation of the listener for onAdPresent event that returns these values. I hope this solves your question too (if it's still there).

Comment: Re iOS, the plugin has the code for setting up with iOS (and Windows). I don't know if that's a recent development on plugin since you used it or if the code is the same and not working, I haven't tried it yet.

Comment: yes it’s been months since my last update I’ll give it a try to see if with this it work for me on iOS another thing msg me directly maybe we can help each other out with future projects

Comment: hope it works on iOS too, as I'll be building for it in the coming weeks, too. I don't seem being able to find your contact details in your profile.

Answer (score 0):

I've been working on this issue for about an hour now, and due to the limited event listeners on the cordova-plugin-admobpro plugin, the best solution I was able to come up with was to set a timer for 10 seconds (the minimum ad length) and then wait for the onAdDismiss event to fire. Obviously this still means if a video is exited 10 seconds into a 30 second ad they would still receive credit.

See rough example below:

```
    var canCredit;


//button event clicked to load/autodisplay ad

function showVideoAd(){


    canCredit='no';

//start timer


setTimeout(function(){

    canCredit='yes';

}, 10000); //10 seconds


 AdMob.prepareRewardVideoAd({
        adId: 'ca-app-pub-3839382062281896/9043804687',
        autoShow: true,
      });




}

function creditReward(){


//credit reward code here



}

//once ad is dismissed check if 10 seconds is up, if so, credit reward

$(document).on('onAdDismiss', function(e){

    if(canCredit == 'yes')
        creditReward();


});
```

With the code provided in the documentation (and your answer), you can click out of the ads instantly and still receive the reward.

Comment: Great I’ll give this a try to see how it’ll work on the app thank you for your response!